# Is my syntax off or am I just doing this entirely wrong?

Tags: shell, unix

```
var1= grep "$1" ./[FILE] | wc -l
if [ -s ./[FILE] ] && [ "$var1" -eq 1 ]
```

then

```
echo "it worked"

fi
```

I'm trying to get var1 to have an integer value by using the command:

```
 grep "$1" ./[FILE] | wc -l
```

I'm not sure if it is actually setting the value to the one that I assume the command is outputting because in my echo "$var1" it is echoing the value I expect. However, in my if statement:

```
if [ -s ./[FILE] ] && [ "$var1" -eq 1]
```

I continually get an illegal number error.

Comment: You can't use HTML tags like `<p>` in shell scripts.

Comment: Can you not just show your script ? Instead of giving snippets of lines?

Comment: It's actually not a very large script, as it only needs to search a file to make sure that it contains a string(userid) and then output another string(the person's name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regards to this:

```
var1= grep "$1" ./[FILE] | wc -l
if [ -s ./[FILE] ] && [ "$var1" -eq 1 ]
```

In shell scripting you can't have spaces on either side of the `=` in an assignment. The way that first line reads, you are running `grep` after assigning an empty string to `var1`. I suspect your intention was to capture the output of `wc` and assign that value to `var1`, which would be, as pointed out in another answer:

```
var1=$(grep "$1" ./[FILE] | wc -l)
```

However, as also pointed out, you can skip the `wc` part by changing that to

```
var1=$(grep -c "$1" ./[FILE])
```

One additional observation - if your `[FILE]` is zero-sized, `grep` isn't going to find anything, anyways, so there's really no need for that whole `if ... && ...` construct. Instead, those two lines could simply be:

```
if (( $(grep -c "$1" ./[FILE]) == 1 ))
then
  echo "it worked"
....
```

If the `echo` bit is one single command, that can even be shortened to this:

```
(( $(grep -c "$1" ./[FILE]) == 1 )) && echo "it worked"
```

Comment: The point of this exercise is to understand how if statements work in shell scripting, but yeah that's also a possibility. Thanks I didn't know about the space thing beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off just doing

```
var1=$(grep -c "$1" ./[FILE])
```

> ```
> -c, --count
>          Only a count of selected lines is written to standard output.
> ```